# Why "The purchase identifier was invalid" appears after app launched on App Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I implemented In-App-Purchase (3 types of subscription) on my app in Swift with StoreKit.
During using sandbox test, it worked well. But after I submitted my app and started to sell it on App Store, the error "The purchase identifier was invalid" appeared on the app.

If the product ID or secret code were invalid, the sandbox test must't have succeeded I think...
I don't know what should I fix.

Comment: Have your IAPs been approved and cleared for sale?

Comment: Yes, it was already turned on. So I turned it off at first, and soon turned it on. But the error still appears.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find out the solution?